# Can't access phpMyAdmin on Windows 10 (Xampp)

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I just reinstalled Xampp onto my laptop, I Apache and MySQL both running with ports 4433, 8080 (Apache) and 3306 (MySQL) but for some reason I can't access the localhost/phpMyAdmin. I've tried https://localhost/phpMyAdmin, http://localhost/phpMyAdmin, https://localhost:8080/phpMyAdmin and http://localhost:8080/phpMyAdmin but once the page loads it shows up as "IIS 10.0 Detailed Error"

Is there any help someone can give me?

Thank You!

Comment: If the error shows up as IIS error, then you are not running XAMPP, but IIS.

Comment: @Shadow okay, so what do I do?

Comment: Install XAMPP and not IIS...

Comment: @Shadow I do have it installed though. It's literally running right now. Could it be a different issue?

Comment: @Shadow there seems to be another error. I stopped the control panel and tried to quit but two error messages came up . "Exception EAccessViolation in module xampp-control.exe at 0025B2AE. Access violation at address 0065B2AE in module 'xampp-control.exe'. Read of address 00000042" and another "Error: Cannot create file "C:\xampp\xampp-control.ini" Access is denied."